# Multiple animation triggers in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to use 2 different animations triggers in the same DIV element, but only one of them works.

*.ts*

```
trigger('openClose', [
      state(
        'open',
        style({
          transform: 'rotate(0deg)'
        })
      ),
      state(
        'close',
        style({
          transform: 'rotate(0deg)'
        })
      ),
      transition('* => close', [
        animate('0.09s', style({ transform: 'rotate(180deg)' }))
      ]),
      transition('* => open', [
        animate('0.09s', style({ transform: 'rotate(180deg)' }))
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('stretchAccordionDesktop', [
      state(
        'close',
        style({
          width: '908px'
        })
      ),
      state(
        'open',
        style({
          width: '454px'
        })
      ),
      transition('* => close', [animate('0.2s')]),
      transition('* => open', [animate('0.1s')])
    ])
```

*.html*

```
<div
  class="tipsAccordion round-box clickable"
  (click)="isShowTips = !isShowTips"
  *ngIf="!isMobile && tips.length > 0"
  [@stretchAccordionDesktop]="!isShowTips ? 'open' : 'close'"
>
  <p>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!isShowTips" [@openClose]="!isShowTips ? 'open' : 'close'"
      >expand_more</mat-icon
    >
    <mat-icon *ngIf="isShowTips" [@openClose]="isShowTips ? 'close' : 'open'"
      >expand_less</mat-icon
    >
    <span class="nr">{{ tips.length }}</span> Tips
  </p>
</div>
```

as you see I want my mat-icon "arrow" icon to rotate itself when clicked, which works fine until I add another trigger to my div element to stretch it as you can see in my code above. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `animateChild()` to your parent animation to trigger the children's animation:

```js
trigger('stretchAccordionDesktop', [
      state(
        'close',
        style({
          width: '908px'
        })
      ),
      state(
        'open',
        style({
          width: '454px'
        })
      ),
      transition('* => close', [
        animate('0.2s')
        query('@*', animateChild(), { optional: true }) // <!---- add this line
      ]),
      transition('* => open', [
        animate('0.1s')
        query('@*', animateChild(), { optional: true }) // <!---- add this line
      ])
    ])
```

Comment: it is not smooth and it is lagging very much, it almost seems like the animations doesn't run. Is there a chance to run both animations at the same time?

Comment: I think the performance issue is because you are animating nested components. I would maybe try to restructure the template a little bit so the animation are running on sibling components instead of nested component